# Once I completed Stripe payment and then create-payment-intent can't fetch

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

### I have a payment system with stripe payment intents and I want to create a succesfull paymnent . but once i  payment then show this eorror in server side

C:\Project_Programing_hero\assainment-list\assainment-12\best-tech-server\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:40
return new StripeInvalidRequestError(rawStripeError);
^

StripeInvalidRequestError: This value must be greater than or equal to 1.

**on client side in checkoutFrom.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof (totalPrice));
```

fetch('http://localhost:5000/create-payment-intent', {

```
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ price: parseInt(totalPrice) }),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            const dataClientSecret = data?.clientSecret;
            if (dataClientSecret) {
                setClientSecret(dataClientSecret)
            }
        })
}, [totalPrice])

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
        return;
    }

    const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    if (card == null) {
        return;
    }
    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card,
    });

    if (error) {
        console.log('[error]', error);
        setCardError(error.message)
    } else {
        console.log('[PaymentMethod]', paymentMethod);
        setCardError('')
    }
    // confirm card payment
    setCardSuccess('')
    setProcessing(true)
    const { paymentIntent, error: intentError } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
        `${clientSecret}`,
        {
            payment_method: {
                card: card,
                billing_details: {
                    name: customerName,
                    email: email
                },
            },
        },
    );
    if (intentError) {
        setCardError(intentError?.message)
        setProcessing(false)
    } else {
        setCardError('')
        setTransitionId(paymentIntent.id)
        console.log(paymentIntent);
        setCardSuccess('Congrats,Your payment is compiled')

        // store payment to database
        const payment = {
            order: _id,
            transitionId: paymentIntent.id
        }
        axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/order/${_id}`, payment)
            .then(res => {
                setProcessing(false)
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

“This value must be greater than or equal to 1” error shows that the [amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount) [0] param set in the payment intent creation request is smaller than 1. In the endpoint `/create-payment-intent` at your server, you will need to ensure **request.price** is greater than or equal to 1, and correctly assign into [amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount) param. For example,

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: request.price,
  currency: 'usd',
  automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
});
```

Apart from the server side, you should also make sure that the **totalPrice** at frontend is greater than or equal to 1 before passing to server.

```
body: JSON.stringify({ price: parseInt(totalPrice) }),
```

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount

Comment: It's not worked for me and please give me another answer.

Comment: Can you console.log the request.price before the paymentIntents.create function at backend? Do you get the amount that's the same as frontend?